# Angular search results not visible in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to search inside my project.
Inside the navigation template (nav.html) I have my search form.
The results should be displayed after the click on the search button inside the results template (search.html)
A click on the search button also "redirects" always to the results view.
The value from the search form is also always retrieved by the search controller (SearchCtrl) but from that point I am stuck!

I won't get my results displayed in my results view. Any ideas how to solve that?
Thanks in advance!

Here are my code snippets (simplified):

### Main page (index.html):

```
<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-include="'views/nav.html'"></nav>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="view-container" ng-view></div>

</body>
```

### Navigation view (nav.html):

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right" ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search games" ng-model="search.text">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-Click="findValue(search.text); redirect('/search/')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="color:#fff;">{{search.text}}</div>
    </form>
</div>
```

### Search view (search.html):

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results" data-id="{{result.short}}">
    <div>
        <h4>{{result.name}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Routing:

```
.when('/search/', {
    controller: 'SearchCtrl',
    templateUrl: urlViews + 'search.html'
})
```

### Factory:

```
// Call the service
var callRestService = function ($resource) {
    var res = $resource('data/:id'); // Note the full endpoint address --> id contains the url params!
    return res;
};
callRestService.$inject = ['$resource'];
app.factory('callRestService', callRestService);

// Call the search
var Search = function ($resource) {
    return {text:''};
};
Search.$inject = ['$resource'];
app.factory('Search', Search);
```

### Controller:

```
var NavbarCtrl = function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.getClass = function(path) {
        var substr = 3,
            cur_path = $location.path().substr(substr, path.length);
        if (cur_path == path) {
            if($location.path().substr(0).length > 1 && path.length == 1) {
                return '';
            } else {
                return 'active';
            }
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    };

    // toggle active class for nav
    $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
        return viewLocation === $location.path();
    };

    // redirect on click
    $scope.redirect = function (path) {
        $location.path(path);
    };
};
NavbarCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$location'];
app.controller('NavbarCtrl', NavbarCtrl);


var SearchCtrl = function ($scope, callRestService, Search) {

    $scope.json = 'data.json';

    $scope.findValue = function(Search) {

        var searchValue = Search;

        console.log('searchValue: ', searchValue); // all search input will be displayed!

        var res = callRestService.get({
                id: $scope.json
            }, function() {
                $scope.games = res.games;
                $scope.results = [];

                angular.forEach($scope.games, function(key, value) {
                    if (key.name === searchValue) {
                        $scope.results.push({
                            name: key.name,
                            short: key.short
                        });
                    }

                    console.log('searchValue - in: ', searchValue); // all search input will be displayed!
                    console.log('$scope.results: ', $scope.results); // all results will be displayed!
                });

            }
        );

    };

};
SearchCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'callRestService', 'Search'];
app.controller('SearchCtrl', SearchCtrl);
```

View in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9PAAsb?p=info)

Comment: Any chance you can make a quick Plunkr with that? Just to see if a new scope is not created after the $location.path() call...

Comment: I will do that ;) Hold on ...

Comment: Plunkr created: http://plnkr.co/edit/9PAAsb?p=info

Comment: I'll have a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it.

The function `redirect()` that you have on your button, is on the controller `NavCtrl`, which is on your `<ul>`, but your div containing the button is OUTSIDE of the `<ul>`.

On your plunkr I added the function to your SearchCtrl and it works.
Here http://plnkr.co/edit/FCAEpg?p=preview

And also you get a second $scope created when you redirect to search, hence when you first request the findValue method, then move the user, the first $scope gets populated with your results, but your view is linked to the second $scope, which has nothing... Solution (temporary), is to move the user, then do the search while getting the value of your search through $routeParams.

Not the cleanest, but works... Plunkr updated

Comment: Thanks!

I see your changes but there are still no results beeing displayed in the serach view (search.html). Did you try it with an item from the data.json? E.g.: 5 Card Solitaire

Comment: ah no sorry I didn't, I thought the main issue was with the redirection. Let me have a look

Comment: Ok, thanks!

I just updated the plunkr with the info regarding testing. Should have done that before . Sorry!

Comment: OK it's because you have two different scopes. You create one when you attach SearchCtrl to the button's div, and then there's another one when you redirect to search. But that second one did not receive the call of the method to search. I'd be you I'd temporarily save my results in the service, and call them on controller load... for now at least. I'll make an example

Comment: Ah damn, it's a resource, change of plan. Let's redirect but from the NavCtrl and call findValue each time someone accesses the route. Code coming

Comment: ok done. Updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/FCAEpg?p=preview
But honestly, it's not the cleanest way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will apply your changes to my project. I guess I will then have to think about a better solution for the future?